# Which part should be frozen during transfer learning?

Tags: machine-learning, transfer-learning, finetuning

I want to use transfer learning and fine tuning and I need to decide which part of
the original model will be used and which part will be frozen. I'm thinking about four possilbe cases:
small/large new dataset and this set is similar/not similar to the original dataset. What should be done to achieve best results in each of the cases?

Comment: [cs231 - 2016](https://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/) has the precise answer to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: transfer learning principles]

Ideally I follow the below rules for performing transfer learning, I could do successful object detection using Yolo model by traning only last layer and was able to do leaf classification by training good number of layers.

Comment: I think, for the last cell - there is not much point in fine-tuning as it will a full training and you also carry the load of a pre-trained model. Better have your own model from scratch

Comment: Agree, but in case you are doing these on images, the initial layers atleast helps you in identifying edges etc., that might help to some extent.